# email address non required

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

I am developing a website and an application for it using Woocommerce and Ionic with the help of Woocommerce's API. I'm trying to make email field in the register page optional and make customers register with their mobile numbers and passwords.

I have no idea how to do so, should I let the email field to become null inside the database or is there any workarounds in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has a very broad documentation, one topic in it is about [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/), you can easily set `billing_email` to not be required. (code untested)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'WPSE0309_woocommerce_checkout_fields');

function WPSE0309_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;

     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Is it work in woocommerce rest api?